# Reading a dictionary that has function calls

Tags: python

How to read a file that has complex nested dict/list with some values as a function call.

```
Data = {'key1' : func1(arg1, arg2)}.....
```

How to read it as a dictionary so that I can query values after loading the file.

Comment: If you read if from file, you won't keep the function call

Comment: Any chance we could see your code and correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the name of the module in which the function is located and the name of the function

```
import importlib

# Suppose it is loaded from a file
d = {
    "module": "my_lib",
    "function": "f1",
    "args": ["Hello", "World!"]
}

module = importlib.import_module(d["module"])

ext_func = getattr(module, d["function"])
ext_func(*d["args"])
```

It is assumed that you have my_lib.py with the following content

```
def f1 (s1, s2):
     print (s1, s2)
```

And don't forget to create `__init__.py`